# Informatica Repository Query to get Lookup Connection

Tags: sql, informatica

Within Informatica I have a Mapping which uses a unconnected lookup. This Mapping I use in a `Session` wherein I define a Relational DB connection for this lookup transformation.

Now, which repository tables will I have to query to get the connection names for all my lookups in my sessions? 
I tried `REP_SESS_WIDGET_CNXS`, but there are only connection names for sources and targets of my sessions.

Any idea on this one?